# Problem with DNS after vpn connection on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dns, vpn

When I connecting to VPN my internet connection is lost. But ping via `ping 8.8.8.8` works fine, but if I try to `ping google.com` its doesn't work. I made the following steps from this article https://datawookie.netlify.app/blog/2018/10/dns-on-ubuntu-18.04/ but this didn't help. The weirdest part is that it sometimes works but sometimes it doesn't. I have no idea what wrong

Answer (score 0):

There was problem with my wi-fi router configuration, i just add static dns `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`